# service which is started by AlarmManager is not stopped from an Activity

Tags: android

I set an AlarmManager object to start a service.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); //context = getApplicationContext();
Intent alarmServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmHandlingService.class);
alarmServiceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
alarmServiceIntent.putExtra("alarmId", _id); //_id is a "long" value
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, (int)_id, alarmServiceIntent, 0); 
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
```

The `onStartCommand(..., ..., ...)` of `AlarmHandlingService` works as it has to work and when it has to work. There isn't any problem:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    long alarmId = intent.getLongExtra("alarmId", -1);
    Intent someActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
    someActivityIntent.putExtra("alarmId", alarmId);
    someActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(someActivityIntent);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

But then, when a new activity is opened (SomeActivity) and I call `stopService(...)`, the service is not stopped:

```
stopService(new Intent(context, AlarmHandlingService.class)); //context = getApplicationContext();
```

This is the declaration of my service class in the manifest:
    `<service android:name="***myPackageName***.AlarmHandlingService"></service>`

I tried to debug and noticed only that the `registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)` function of `android.content.ContextWrapper` class is called when I call the `stopService`.

Comment: what is there in your onDestroy() ?

Comment: I do nothing with onDestroy. Isn't it called after stopService? And my stopService is not called at all...@Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Service is stopped");
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

Comment: Aaaaaa!!!! Thank you VERY-VERY MUCH, NetStarter:) I moved code from stopService to onDestroy and now it works:)

Comment: oh gr8 it helped and always welcome i thought not calling cancel method would be a problem.

Comment: I call `cancel` earlier, before stopping the service. Then only I call the `stopService` from Activity. Also I had some functions in my Service's overriden `stopService` method, which was never called. I moved the code from Service's `stopService` to Service's `onDestroy` and now the problem is solved:) Thank you again:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you comments you are not doing anything when your stopService is being called.

When you call stopService it will actually give a call to the function stopService().(which is being done in your application).

You must use onDestroy Method.

```
public void onDestroy ()
```

*Added in API level 1*

Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed. The service should clean up any resources it holds (threads, registered receivers, etc) at this point. Upon return, there will be no more calls in to this Service object and it is effectively dead. 
(*Do not call this method directly*).

and the other problem is you are not calling anything to stop your alarm manager.

you must have called [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) method for `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 0):

please try with new activity.

```
stopService(new Intent(this, AlarmHandlingService.class));
```

Comment: OP is calling it like that only `stopService(new Intent(context, AlarmHandlingService.class));`